# How many children did Parashara have besides Vyasa?

Tags: mahabharata, parashara

Parashara is known for being the father of Vyasa. Did he have any other children besides Vyasa?

Comment: As per site rules, once your suspension period is over, you will get back all the reputation points you have earned (around 1600).

Comment: See the following post on Meta -- https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1077/4732